# Running Proguard on Android app with libs written in Scala

Tags: android, scala, proguard

I have an android project that will be written in Java but will utilize some libs written in Scala.

I'm using the AndroidProguardScala plugin to build be a minimal Scala lib, but it doesn't seem to pick up the fact that the JARs in my project also need some of the Scala API included, causing the app to fail when these methods are called.

What am I missing?

Comment: Things are not included so much at the jar level as at the package level.

Comment: How are you including the jars in your project?  Just putting them in the libs directory, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specifically include them inside your proguard.cfg file.  Just indicate that you want to keep those packages. Thats all there is to it.

Comment: Just request that those packages be kept that you need tin the proguard.cfg file.

Comment: The packages in my JARs or the actual Scala packages?

Comment: I don't have a proguard.cfg file. The AndroidProguardPlugin runs the tasks automatically and it doesn't seem like the config files are editable.

Comment: I would take a look at the configuration used by the sbt android plugin (https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/). That may match minimally what you want.

Comment: If you look at the generated proguard_postprocessed.conf file, you should see a line starting with "# Inserting file" and then a filename.  You can edit that file, and it will be inserted in the final configuration.  (If you can think of a way that I can make this more clear, please submit a bug at https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala/issues?state=open)

Comment: One small clarification - you want to include references to the jars as -libraryjars entries in the proguard configuration.  The plugin wants to generate a jar file that's purely the scala libraries, not your code.  Also, you shouldn't have to do this manually.  If the plugin isn't doing this for you, please submit a bug at https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala/issues?state=open.  The plugin should try to find everything on the classpath and create the right libraryjars entries for you.